# Arrays and function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

How do pass an array of pointers to functions as a argument to a function? If the types of the functions are void and so is the pointer, how do you access the functions?

```
int main() {

  void(*fun_ptr[])(void) = {fun1, fun2, fun3};
  pickFun(fun_ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

All 3 functions only print a message and are declared as void

```
void pickFun(void *function_ptr[])
{
   int pick = 0;
   while(pick != 0)
   {
     scanf("%i", &pick);
    *(function_ptr + (pick - 1));
   }
 }
```

I can never get the function's printf statements to appear when a function is chosen. The program just loops and never prints the message contained in each function. Any suggestions or clues?

Comment: First of all, if you have an array use array-indexing syntax, like e.g. `function_ptr[pick - 1]` instead, it makes it much clearer what you are doing. Secondly, you don't actually *call* the functions.

Comment: Oh, and thirdly, think again about your loop condition...

Comment: `int pick = 0; while(pick != 0) {...` Here while loop never gets a chance.

Comment: Sorry bout that my official code didnt have that while loop fail. My issue in general was with the array of function pointers

Comment: The compiler complained no matter what i did to pass the array into it because of array of void and such errors. Basically, the user enters 1 - 3 to choose one of those 3 functions to print out a message and if the user enters 0 then program ends

Answer (score 1):

Function parameter `void *function_ptr[]` is of type `pointer to pointer to`void`. You need to change it to

```
void pickFun(void (*function_ptr[])(void));
```

Also note that, as others pointed out in comments, program never enters the loop body. Better to use `do while` loop here

```
void pickFun(void *function_ptr[])
{
   do
   {
        scanf("%i", &pick);
        //*(function_ptr + (pick - 1));
        function_ptr[pick-1]();     //Function call. pick should not be greater than 3
   } while(pick != 0)
 }
```

Comment: In other words, *exactly* as it is declared in `main`, less the initializer.

Comment: I changed main to this int main() {

 void(*fun_ptr[])(void) = {fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4};
 pickFun(fun_ptr);
 return (0);
}
I changed the pickFun to this
voidpickFun(void(*function_ptr[])(void)) { }

inside pick fun I used function_ptr[pick - 1] for each of the 3 legal answers and 0 to terminate

My pickFun declaration is this
                                void selectFunction(void (*[]));

The complier errors saying the following

 'void pickFun(void *[])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__cdecl *[4])(void)' to 'void *[]'

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can call your functions with:

```
(*function_ptr[pick-1])();
```

or (yuck):

```
(*(function_ptr + (pick-1)))();
```

or:

```
function_ptr[pick-1]();
```

or:

```
(function_ptr + (pick-1))();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "How to pass an array of pointers to functions as a argument to a function?"

Comment: It answers the question, "How do you access the functions?"